# Concatenate (++) lists without overlap

Tags: list, haskell, concatenation

Imagine I have two lists:

```
l1 = "Hey there"
l2 = "there is a turtle"
```

how do I "concatenate" the lists but remove the start of the second list that matches the end of the first?

```
magic l1 l2 == "Hey there is a turtle"
```

---

More examples,

```
magic "What's going on" "ing on in the world" == "What's going on in the world"
magic [1,2,3,2] [2,3,2,1] == [1,2,3,2,1]
magic [1..10] [5..20] == [1..20]
magic [1,2] [1,2] == []
```

What I'm looking for is something that will concatenate the lists and then remove the parts - only at the "joint" - where the lists matched up.

---

Things I've looked at:

- `++` just concatenates, so isn't what I'm after.
- `Data.List`'s `\\` list difference operator starts from the front of the first list and removes the occurrence from the second list no matter where it is, so won't work.
- I couldn't figure out if I could use `stripPrefix` for this, maybe it's doable but my understanding of haskell isn't good enough.

I've also looked through [the entire Data.List](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html) module, and couldn't find anything that does what I want out of the box.

Thus it looks like it's necessary to make our own function to do this, in which case a Prelude-function solution is preferable over something with dependencies.

Comment: I don't think there's a standard library function that helps you very much with this, but it's really not so difficult to code this up yourself, at least if you don't mind _O_ (_n_ ²) complexity.

Comment: @leftaroundabout I can't figure out how to do that, I've been trying for  a while now xD

Comment: Well, the naïve way would be to try out all possible prefixes ([`tails`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.9.1.0/docs/Data-List.html#v:tails) from the first list) that you could possibly strip from the second one. Choose the longest.

Comment: I think you can do it with a simple recursive solution that's `O(length(l1))`: first see whether `l1` is a prefix of `l2`, then whether `tail l1` is a prefix of `l2`, then `tail (tail l1))` is a prefix of `l2`...

Comment: @mb21 `tails` returns a list of lists. Therefore, `tails ...` will never be a prefix of `l2`

Comment: @minseong right, I meant `tail` not `tails` (corrected the comment above)... but `tails` is of course a nice solutions as well.. btw, you don't have to "choose the longest" since "The tails function returns all final segments of the argument, longest first." so it should be O(n), right?

Answer (score 2):

Here's a simple recursive solution:

```
magic x y = f x y y
  where f [] y z = y
        f x [] z = x
        f (x:xs) (y:ys) z = x : if x == y then f xs ys z else f xs z z
```

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to do it:

```
import Data.List
overlap xs ys = xs ++ (ys \\ (head ((tails xs) `intersect` (inits ys))))
```

but I don't find it very attractive and am hoping someone can improve upon it.

Answer (score 0):

Since noone wrote this one up yet:

```
import Data.List (isPrefixOf)

magic xs ys = s' ++ r'
  where
    (s', r') = go xs
    go []    = ([], [])
    go (x:xs)
      | isPrefixOf (x:xs) ys = ([], ys)
      | otherwise            = (x:s, r)
        where
          (s, r) = go xs
```